# New Jersey area Christmas Town

Tags: christmas

Are there any small cities or large towns within a three hour drive of Atlantic City, NJ that go all out during the Christmas season? Specifically: organized public holiday decorations and displays, Christmas music in public areas(live or piped through a sound system), public events, people in costume, etc.

I visited Bethlehem, PA last year and it was incredible.

I visited Philadelphia, PA the year before and was disappointed.

Thank you.

Comment: Baltimore. Head over to the Hamden neighborhood for spectacular Christmas lights. It's legit.

Comment: This is far, far too broad to be answerable; the swath of the country you want suggestions from covers hundreds of municipalities, tens of thousands of square miles, and millions of people. Philadelphia as a whole won't have a big Christmas or winter celebration—it's too large and too diverse—but individual neighborhoods will; if you couldn't find Christmas there, you weren't looking in the right place.

Comment: Edited PA to East or Central PA, this narrows it down to less than a three hour drive, perfect for a day trip or overnight stay. The vast number of municipalities in this area is exactly the reason I need suggestions. I don't have time to search a thousand municipal and county websites.

Comment: @AirportChariotCarandLimo The request is still unreasonable because no one here will have spent enough time at enough festivals in enough cities to recommend one or another definitively. It will all come down to personal opinion and anecdotes, which goes against what Stack Exchange aims to provide. Try TripAdvisor, or FlyerTalk, or ThornTree, or Yelp.

Comment: @choster I disagree, If I had come across this question, I would have given Bethlehem, Pa as my answer and listed the reasons why. But I have already done that city and am looking for another one. Also, my question didn't ask for the best city or town, so a person could answer if they live near or have visited a location that met my parameters.

Comment: But one of the explicit off topic close reasons is that we're not a travel agency. This is the sort of thing you'd ask a travel agent for: suggesting locations/attractions.

Comment: A travel agent would not have the local knowledge to answer my question. This travel site is full of Q & A's about sightseeing suggestions.

Comment: The on topic questions are about specific attractions (entry fees, how to get there, stuff like that). The off topic and closed questions are asking "what is there to see".

Comment: The first half of your statement is just not true Roddy, just type "sights" into the search bar.

Comment: It's unfortunate that, when people vote to close for more than one reason, only the majority reason gets quoted. Thanks for trying to edit to make the question less broad but there are other problems here: we don't give "Where should I visit?" recommendations because any such recommendation is just an opinion and nodody's opinion is any better or worse than anyone else's. Ultimately, this isn't the sort of question that works on Stack Exchange.